# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'DATABASE.blog_posts' doesn't exist on 000webhost

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Im using 000webhost.
Recently i installed custom blog script.

When i inserted database details(host/dbname/dbuser/dbpass) i get this error

When i go to blog index.php

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'a5416708_blog.blog_posts' doesn't exist

When i go to blog admin panel index.php, try and login it says this:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'a5416708_blog.blog_members' doesn't exist

Wrong username or password

All I understood is that i need to create those tables, which i need to do in phpmyadmin.

But question is 
1)how do I corrent this error?
2)how do I create/add database tables in phpmyadmin?

---

Have done this part ( creating tables, thanks to Karthic Rajakumar)

Once i did that, i needed user for my admin panel. Where from i downloaded this php blog script, theres told that username and password for that user is "demo".
Which is told in sql script too

```
    INSERT INTO `blog_members` (`memberID`, `username`, `password`, `email`)
VALUES
  (1,'Demo','$2y$10$wJxa1Wm0rtS2BzqKnoCPd.7QQzgu7D/aLlMR5Aw3O.m9jx3oRJ5R2','demo@demo.com');
```

So, when i created thoses tables, I inserted this sql script into database(then I found, that i didn't have to manually really create them), whatever.
When i inserted this sql script into my database with this user and password(which i believe is hashed or something) is main acp user.
Then i deleted this user with ID 1 from .blogs_member (emptyed table) and created new user with another username and password (admin, admin)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should rather contact 00webhost support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 000Webhost, I see you have already created your MySQL Database with the name
`a5416708_blog`. After you create your corresponding tables those error wont show.

Now For your table creation part:
Go to your cpanel in your 000webhost account and then click on phpmyadmin.
When you are inside PHPmyAdmin Click on your database name which is `a5416708_blog` and an page on the right will pop up to create a table
Use this link for reference
[Check this website](https://www.shorttutorials.com/control-panel/create-table-using-phpmyadmin.html)

Alternate Method:
You can Simply Export your database from your local machine where you already have the tables and perform an Import Operation on the 000webhost's phpmyadmin.
[Check this for Importing a MySQL database](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/phpmyadmin/import-database-using-phpmyadmin)